# Post with an HTML-like tag in the body renders correctly in the preview, but not in the post

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25453914/3840170) renders as such when editing:

[image: Answer edited and HTML tag appears in preview]

However, when submitted, the tag does not render (or appear in the http response):

[image: Answer without any HTML tag]

I am not sure where's the appropriate place to file bug reports, but either:

1. the final post should have the tag in it
2. the tag should be stripped from the preview as well

Comment: I've escaped the < and > symbols so it renders correctly now. Though I do agree with you that it would be preferable that the preview matched the actual final rendering.

Comment: Also a weird behaviour the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25453914/revisions) shows that it has always been rendered and that even though I added 2 characters there is no visible diff.

Comment: Seems to be an oddity in the preview when there are "invalid" characters in the tag (the colon) which causes the preview not to strip it properly. But this is already fixed with the new Stacks editor which auto-escapes the angled brackets in this case (you can test it in answers here on Meta).